# created new machine with juju add-machine, but it's in "pending state" for a long time and it's not getting started

Tags: juju

I have installed juju 1.24.0) version in my Ubuntu box and when tried to add a juju machine using juju `add-machine` it's waiting in a pending state for a long time as shown below.

```
juju status
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.24.0.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: pending
    instance-id: charm-local-machine-1
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64
services: {}
```

*Can any one please tell me why the new juju machine is not getting started?*

Answer (score 1):

Juju doesn't know what to do with the machine, as you have no services.  Add a service and juju should assign the unit to the service.  Then it will provision and put your service on it.